# UICollectionView with dynamic and static cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom dynamic cell on a collectionView created on IB which will be filled with data from an array.

I want to add a static cell on the same CollectionView IB.  Is it possible that the static cell to be on the last object of Collection View, no matter what array length is from dynamic cell the static cell would be added as last object?

Comment: so you want to have both: static and dynamic cells? if this is what you want.. i dont'really think this is possible

Comment: @BogdanSomlea Yeah in same CollectionView to have a Dynamic Cell and Static Cell , two cells created on IB on same collectionview one of them will be filled with array one will stay static it wont take any entry data but i want it to be added last after all dynamic cells filled from array. is that possible ?

Comment: i never tried, but i don't think that is possible. But, if it is possible you create the static cell, and override the UICollectionView datasource method: 
    – collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: @BogdanSomlea Thank you. I will try and let you know.

Comment: You should consider the static cell you want, as a dynamic cell but to be used only once. You can always have more than one dynamic cell, but cannot have both together in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code for doing this.. I tried this method... For dynamic cell and static cell...

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

// Retuens the number of sections in collectionview
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if section == 0 {
    return data.count
    }else if section == 1{
        return 1
    }else {
        return 0
    }
}
// Data get's filled into UICollectionView
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    var cell : CollectionCell!// important step...
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

 //do something inside this

        }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
     cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionCell

       //here the static cell...   


    }
    return cell
    }
```

Comment: Will it not crash if we are using same collectioncell with multiple ReuseIdentifier's